# Update with wrong JOIN in SQLAnywhere

Tags: join, sql-update, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm working on a project that uses SQLAnywhere and I found this Query:

```
update MY_TABLE table1 
set table1.column1 = table3.id
from MY_TABLE table2, MY_OTHER_TABLE table3
where table2.some_col = table3.some_col and table2.other_col is null;
```

The problem is, that table1 which is updated and table2/table2 which are joined do not have any link, no constraint. Table1 is completely independent from the other two.

So as far as I can understand it, if the condition in the last line is met for at least one row, then ALL rows of table1 will be updated because then the join-statement is always true.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. I agree ;)

Long answer: It really looks like that there is no connection between table 1 and tables 2 and 3. So based on your input above, I'd expect the mentioned behaviour.

Also I'd remove the implicit JOIN here, as it might causes confusion.